# Saving updates to WordPress post as a revision that is not set live automatically

Tags: wordpress

WP has surprisingly limited multi user revisioning features and the key thing missing for me is the ability for an author role user to be able to update their live posts but for the changes to still require authorisation before going live AND yet for the post not to revert to a pending status whilst it awaits review by another user.

I was hoping that the WP plugin "revisionary" https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/ was going to help me but it doesn't function as I want, which is without new interface elements or the need to use any kind of revision change browsing tool.  In fact I don't think its working with the custom post type I have at all anyhow.

The way I imagine this could work is simply that new submissions are saved into a new revision of the post, a "future" revision so to speak that is one ahead of the current version.    Then later a WP editor/admin user would then review and switch for the older revision that was still live on the website.

I understand what I want to do may not be possible as described but does anyone have any other strategies that could work?  I really want to do this in code for the functions.php file of the theme I am making and avoid plugins.

Comment: There is a dedicated stackexchange for WordPress, try asking there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did indeed ask on the WordPress stack exchange site and eventually answered the question myself.  So for anyone interested head over here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183553/revert-one-revision-of-a-post-progmattically-via-code